# How to disable access to file page (view display mode = full)?

Tags: 7, files, media, entities

I want to **disable access** to the view display page of file by url like ***file/fid***.

What's the good way for this? I have tried to use the hook_node_view() but it not called for the files.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally used the [RABBIT HOLE module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole), it contains a sub-module for managing **file_entity**! :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using below ways :

1. Unpublish your node
2. [Node Page Disable](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_page_disable) module

> Allows easy UI access and disabling of the path /node when not used.
>   This was inspired by a security consideration in the Production Check
>   Module.

3. [Restrict node page view](https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_node_page_view)

> Have you ever used a slideshow nodetype that you need to be published
>   but don't want the node be accessible by itself using then node/XXX
>   path? This module is for you!
>
> With this module you can disable direct access to node pages
>   (node/XXX) based on nodetypes and permissions.
>
> Enable the module and don't forget to configure your permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I prefer to use maintained modules and I already used Rabbit Hole for another project, so I opted for Rabbit Hole but your solution probably works!

Comment: Welcome @kxxxxoo.